# How to submit Salesforce's Web to Lead Forms with AJAX instead of the default submission?

Tags: ajax, forms, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to submit my webtolead form, somethinf that is so simple and basic jQuery, But I am getting CORS origin error :

```
<script>

    // https://www.domainName.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8

    function postFormAjax(formData) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            crossOrigin: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                if (textStatus == "error") {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                }

            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

    postFormAjax({ first_name: "test", email: "test@gmail.com" })

</script>
```

This is the error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I allowed localhost on my Salesforce SETUP :

[image]

Also I feel like there is something important about this field :

[image]

I don't find many clear guides on how to submit webtolead forms via XMLHTTPSREQUEST !!

Any help or indication here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wouah ::))))) !!!!!

Comment: Kindly share the solution